# Как обратиться к массиву data ? (javascript) Мне нужно : если в data('product_id') содержится больше 4 х элементов то вывести на экран приветствие.

Tags: javascript

```
    // ##### REMOVE FROM COMPARE ######

$(document).on( 'click', '.remove a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var button = $(this),
        data = {
            action: yith_woocompare.actionremove,
            id: button.data('product_id'),
            iframe: button.data('iframe'),
            context: 'frontend'
        };
```

Comment: ничего не понятно. Как в `data('product_id')` могут содержатся элементы?

Comment: `if (4 < data.id.split(' ').length ) alert('hello')`